# Thermal hysteresis of shunt regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, thermal

What is the meaning of the "Thermal hysteresis" in shunt regulator datasheet ?

Will it contribute to output tolerance ?

[image]

FYI: It's TL4050C50-Q1 datasheet.

Comment: Did you read note (1)?

Comment: Yes I did read, but I don't understand about the "after cycling to"

Comment: Intense temperature changes cause PERMANENT ERRORS in the regulation setpoint.

Comment: So, you start at (let's say) 25 C.  You measure the voltage. Then you reduce the temperature to -40 C. Then you raise the temperature to 125 C. Then you reduce the temperature to 25 C. Then you measure the voltage again. There will be a difference.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it's a shunt **reference** and not a **regulator**. The term regulator is generally applied to devices that supply power to other chips and circuits. Voltage references are precision devices although there can be some overlap.

Thermal hysteresis is a term used with **references**. If the output is producing a voltage of (say) 5.010 volts then, after a large thermal excursion, the device guarantees to return to within 1.4 mV of where it was previously (all other conditions being equal). So it can be expected to return to between 5.0086 volts and 5.0114 volts. Better references have a smaller value for thermal hysteresis.

Comment: Can I just use the "Shunt reference" as a power supply for IC or I have to use it with the tracking regulator.